# How to auto sum up based on user selections from drop-down

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to calculate Total cost e.g Column A has Drop-down with default value of 4, B has drop down with Default value of 2 and C has total 100 of D2 - D5. I would like to write a VBA code so if user open this Excel sheet it has default value set in column E2 is 2500. If user change the value in A from drop-down to 6 it will add 1000 to E2 and show the sum immediately in E2. If user will change the value in B from drop-down to 4 it will add up 500 to current value in E2. If toal in column is >1000 then it will add up value in E2 to 5000.

I know the logic to do, but new to VBA and don't know the syntax. How can I instantly update value in E2 as soon as user change value in desire column.

```
    Dim data As Variant
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim z As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    x = Range("A1").Value
    y = Range("B1").Value
    z = Range("E2").Value

    z.Value = 2500

    If x = 4 & y = 2 Then
        z.Value = 2500
    If x > 4 Then
        z = z .Value + 500
    If y > 2 Then
        z = z .Value + 1000
    If cTotal > 1000
       z = z .Value + 5000
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, I can't yet comment to ask for clarifying info. Try:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Or Target.Address = "$B$1"
    Then Call YourMacro
    End If
End Sub
```

This should call YourMacro when the values in A1 or B1 are changed.

Comment: Instead of calling macro I am trying to do math as shown following:                      
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Or Target.Address = "$B$1" Then
    
        E2.value = (E2.value + ((A1.value)%4) * 500) + ((B1.value%2) * 1000) )
    
    End If
End Sub                                                                                                                                                                  It is not working. I am getting invalid character for %.